# Excel 2010 32-bit windows 7 64-bit odbc- Connection Issue

Tags: sql, excel, vba

We have a Excel spreadsheet that connects to Sage via a vba odbc connection (Username and Password *'d)

```
Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
With CN
    .Provider = "MSDASQL"
    .ConnectionString = "DSN=SageLine132;UID=******;PWD=******;"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With
```

This connection works fine on our 32-bit windows xp computers with office 2010, but not on the new windows 7 64-bit computers running office 2010 32-bit.
 When I open the odbc32 in the syswow64 folder the system DSN is installed.
Does anyone have any work around for this or a way to connect without accessing the systems DSN (DSN-Less)?

Comment: Hi Jamie. This question is off-topic on programmers.SE, and will likely get closed or migrated. Please take a look at our FAQ :) Also, you should consider editing the title so that it says something about your problem. As it is now, it's likely few people will read it.

Comment: Check this site out: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this has something to do with the executable being stored in `syswow32/` or `syswow64/`.

I've never used Sage, but I previously had an issue with MyODBC driver on 64b system, the resolution here might help you:

> for win 64b users (XP, win7), in order to access your MyODBC driver
>   (or any other DB driver), you need to run the Data Sources from
>   `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.

[image]

> To make the change permanent, you can add a new Data Sources icon in you Control Panel (must do this from the explorer as it will prompt you for confirmation), name it Data Sources x64, and point it to `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

[image]

for the full article, see [here](http://www.frog101.com/archives/68).